# How to redirect browser to shared files or directories using absolute path within ASP.NET Core and authenticated through Active Directory?

Tags: c#, path, uri, microsoft-edge, asp.net-core-3.1

Background: The division I work at within my company has a company intranet webpage with quick links to files and directories located on our local server, and within a shared drive from another server at a different location within the company. The users have the shared drive mapped on their machine using their credentials, and then they can use the home web page to quickly navigate to common files or directories. This worked fine for many years with IE, but it does not in Edge or other common browsers due to a security violation: "Not allowed to load local resource: " Now that IE's support is ending soon we want to get the links working in Edge to use.

Our ASP.NET Core application runs within IIS, and on our local server. Alternatively, I can use an action method instead of the absolute path to a file on the local server since the application is hosted on it. I do this by using the drive letter and full path to the file to read into a byte array and return as a File. I do not know how to do this for the shared server, where users can download files and open up a folder within the browser.

Currently we have static links to a file like: `<a href="file://///server-name/Folder/file.docx">File</a>`

or Directory: `<a href="file://///shared-server-name/Folder">Directory</a>`

I can copy the absolute path into any browser: file://///shared-server-name/Folder and it will show me the folder and its contents. I just can't do it through the HTML markup outside of IE.

What I've tried so far:

Instead of the static links, I tried redirecting to the absolute path using an action method in the controller:

```
public ActionResult GetFile()
{
  redirect("shared-server-name/Folder") 
}
```

This returns an error in the browser: "It looks like the webpage at https://localhost:*****/home/getfile might be having issues, or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

I tried doing impersonation to see if it was because of the app identity the application was using:

```
IPrincipal p = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
if (p.Identity is WindowsIdentity wid)
{
    
    await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(wid.AccessToken, () => {
        bool exists= Exists("shared-server-name/Folder");

        log.Debug(exists);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
}
```

returns false for exists.

I understand the reason for the security error, but because this is an intranet site, and the access to the shared drive is only through users who are provisioned to it, we'd like to keep the same setup within Edge going forward.

Answer (score 1):

From [this blog](https://textslashplain.com/2019/10/09/navigating-to-file-urls/) written by EricLaw (Edge PM),  we can know that

> For security reasons, Microsoft Edge 76+ and Chrome impose a number of restrictions on file:// URLs, including forbidding navigation to file:// URLs from non-file:// URLs.

The behavior is by design in Edge and there's no option to disable this navigation blocking in Edge. The only thing you can do is using one of the three workarounds listed in the blog:

> 1. Open the website in IE mode.
> 2. Use extensions like [Enable local file links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld).
> 3. Enable group policy [IntranetFileLinksEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#intranetfilelinksenabled) for Edge 95+.

For the group policy, please note that `https://localhost/` is considered internet zone by default and can't be configured by the policy.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was hoping it was just an issue with the static links, and I could get around it programmatically, but doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: No, unfortunately you can't get around it programmatically. If it's in a company organization, configure IE mode or use group policy will be convenient.